# Using google charts from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, google-visualization

I'm trying to get Google Charts to work from a MySQL DB.

I've created an array & can see that it is populated, when viewing source on the live page

However, the chart doesn't appear. Would anyone be able to advise me why this might be?

**Head Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
 google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
 function drawChart() {
 var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([

 ['Date', 'Total Orders'],
 ['2017-9-6',200],['2017-8-6',1500],['2017-7-7',800],['2017-7-3',1,800],['2017-7-2',200],['2017-6-13',10000],['2017-10-5',800],['2017-10-12',4,500],['',], 
 ]);

 var options = {
 title: 'Orders Per Day'
 };
 var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("columnchart"));
 chart.draw(data, options);
 }
 </script>
```

**Body Script**

```
<h3>Column Chart</h3>
 <div id="columnchart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Comment: have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: Thank you for your reply :) - I have checked and noticed it says "Row 8 has 1 columns, but must have 2" - I can't really understand the error, as you can see in the above, row 8 has enough values

Comment: The row number maybe 0 indexed because your 9th row only has 1 column. You added a comma but no numeric value is in that one.

Comment: and the row before the last has 3 columns...